# iReport: @ sql variable is not recognized

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using *Sybase 15* and have a *SP* which returns a result set like this:

```
SELECT foo,
       bar,
       etc,
       xyz,
       ...
      @temp_id
FROM #table
ORDER BY 2,3 DESC
```

When this gets to *iReport* the query shows the field name is blank. It knows that the field type is *java.lang.Integer* but I can see no way to create a field for it in the report.  If I give it a name - *`@temp_id`* I get an error telling me the field isn't found. Same thing if I try it in *JasperReports*.

The strange thing - to me anyway - is that in my Eclipse data explorer it also shows no label for that column. Nor does it for the *JasperReports* Dataset and Query Dialog when I ask it to Read Fields.

I tried just calling it *`COLUMN_15`* but that didn't work either.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you change the query by using a column alias?  Something like `@temp_id as temp_id`?

Comment: Nope. It is a stored proc I am stuck with using.  I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Have you tried using either `[@temp_id]` or `"@temp_id"`?

Comment: Neither works.  Both return an error 'net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unknown column name : temp_id'  I changed the <fieldDescription../> and the field name in the Outline view.

Comment: @djailer May be this faq help you: [iReport - Calling Stored Procedures](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-calling-stored-procedures). You can also look at [Calling Sybase Procedure in Reports Wizard](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/514162/calling-sybase-procedure-reports-wizard) post